# Deploying Universal DirectX app to Windows Phone 8.1 device

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, directx, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have been playing around with DirectX on Windows Phone 8.1 through the Universal App Template and in the process I've noticed that no matter which of my solutions I am opening, whether it be a Universal DirectX template within Visual Studio or code samples from MSDN; whenever I set the default Project in the solution to the Windows Phone 8.1 Project, I dont get an option to deploy to my device(s), instead only the 6 emulators appear.

If I set the default project in the solution to the Windows 8.1 version I am given the option to run on both the device and emulators and if I create a Windows Phone 8.1 DirectX (Silverlight) app it gives me the option to deploy to both the device and emulators. So this problem is only for deploying a DirectX (Universal) app to a Windows Phone 8.1 device

To go a step further, I have tried generating an APPX and manually deploying the DirectX (Universal) app to my various devices, but even though the deployment tool that comes with the 8.1 SDK says that it was successful, it doesn't appear on the devices app lists.

---

So I want to know, is it even possible to deploy a DirectX (Universal) app to a Windows Phone Device? and if it is possible, how to set up the solution to allow deploying to my Windows Phone devices?

Thank you.

Comment: try: create a new universal d3d app, right click the windows phone project and select 'Set as startup project',  then set the solution platform to 'ARM'. The 'Device' option should now available.

Comment: Hey, that worked. Thank you very much. I'd vote you up, but I cant see a spot for it within comments.

Comment: awesome. I reposted as an answer that you can accept.

Comment: Just accepted it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. create a new universal d3d app
2. right click the windows phone project and select 'Set as startup
   project'
3. set the solution platform to 'ARM'

The 'Device' option should now be available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to deploy to the phone device.

- You need a Windows Phone with 8.1 on it.
- Plug it into an enabled USB port.
- Unlock the phone. The name of the tool that unlocks the phone is
  "Windows Phone Developer Registration (8.1)"; it's available by
  searching from the start menu (it isn't listed in the Visual Studio
  tools menu).

Comment: Already have those three done. The thing is though that I'm not getting the option to deploy a DirectX app to the phone, every other type of 8.1 app will deploy fine, but I just dont get the option for DirectX